# What is the purpose of a film leader on a digital production?

Tags: production

I have a few internal production (draft) copies of some episodes of a TV show and have noticed that each has a film leader before the episode.

The show is recorded and distributed purely on digital, and the film leader is removed for the final consumer release.

In this case, what is the purpose of the film leader?